# Mutual information decrease with coarse-graining

Tags: probability, information-theory, correlation, entropy

Let $X,A,Y,B,C,D$ be random binary variables. $D$ is independent from $X,A,C$ and $C$ is independent from $Y,B,D$.

Is it true that:

If $I(Y:B|D=0)\leq \epsilon$ then $I(X\oplus Y:A\oplus B|C=0,D=0)\leq \epsilon \times I(X:A|C=0)$.

This result seems intuitive and I managed to show it for $\epsilon=0$ and $\epsilon=1$, but maybe in the general case we should have a function $f(\epsilon)$ on the right hand side and not simply $\epsilon$. If the result is true, how would you show it using the data processing inequality, the chain rule etc.?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

First, let's simplify by noting that the variables $D$ and $C$ are unnecessary in your question.  Indeed, since $X,A,C$ are independent from $D$, $I(X:A|C=0)=I(X:A|C=0,D=0)$.  Similarly, since $Y,B,D$ are independent from $C$, $I(Y:B|D=0)=I(Y:B|C=0,D=0)$.  So, we can just consider your problem conditioned on $C=D=0$.

Thus, your question can be rephrased as: If $X,Y,A,B$ are binary random variables, does $I(Y:B)\leq \epsilon$ imply $I(X\oplus Y:A\oplus B)\leq f(\epsilon) \times I(X:A)$?

Without any further constraints, the answer is no.  To see this, let $X,A$ be independent Bernoulli(1/2), let $Y=0$ and let $B=X \oplus A$. Then $I(X:A)=0$, but $I(X\oplus Y:A\oplus B)=I(X:X)=1$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer Tom. Sorry I didn't detail all the constraints, but my question looked horrible from start to add stuff to it. Indeed there are constraints that allow us to circumvent situations like the one you described. X,Y,B,A are Bernoulli(1/2) and (X,A) is independent from (Y,B). I found some results using the Hirchfeld-Gebelein-Renyi correlation: $f(\epsilon)=\rho(X,Y)^2=(2p(Y\oplus B=0)-1)^2$. In my situation the bound should not be tight but I didn't find better results.

Comment: HGR maximal correlation will work only in special cases (i.e., when you are dealing with a DSBS).  See http://arxiv.org/abs/1304.6133 for details.